# Pivoting a Pandas Dataframe, no numeric types, index is not unique

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to convert some string data into columns, but have had a difficult time utilizing [past responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442214/pivoting-a-pandas-dataframe-containing-strings-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate) because I do not have a unique index or multi-index that I could use.

Sample format

```html
  index location field         value
1 location1 firstName A
2 location1 lastName B
3 location1 dob         C 
4 location1 email         D
5 location1 title         E
6 location1 address1 F
7 location1 address2 G
8 location1 address3 H
9 location1 firstName I
10 location1 lastName J
11 location1 dob         K
12 location1 email         L
13 location1 title         M
14 location1 address1 N
15 location1 address2 O
16 location1 address3 P
40 location2 firstName Q
41 location2 lastName R
42 location2 dob         S
43 location2 email         T
44 location2 title         U
45 location2 address1 V
46 location2 address2 W
47 location2 address3 X
```

Format I'd like to pivot to:

```html
location firstName lastName dob email title address1 address2 address3
location1 A B C D E F G H
location1 I J K L M N O P
location2 Q R S T U V W X
```

The closest I've come to achieving this is by using aggfuc='first', but this I need all values for each location and not just the first.

Format I'd like to pivot to:

```html
df = df.pivot_table(index='location',columns='field',values='value',aggfunc='first')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pivot with a surrogate column. Here's a solution using `cumsum` + `set_index` + `unstack`.

```
v = df.set_index(['location', 'field', df.field.eq('firstName').cumsum()]).unstack(-2) 
v.index = v.index.droplevel(-1)
v.columns = v.columns.droplevel(0)

field     address1 address2 address3         dob      email firstName  \
location                                                                
location1        F        G        H          C           D         A   
location1        N        O        P           K          L         I   
location2        V        W        X           S          T         Q   

field     lastName      title  
location                       
location1        B          E  
location1        J          M  
location2        R          U
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this answer a little more please? about what surrogate here means and maybe some comments about that complex first line?