# Pivot dataframe with columns constant withing the index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stata

Suppose I have the following dataframe, where both `Y` and `Z` are constant within `ID`:

```
   ID TYPE  X    Y   Z
0   1    A  1  foo  10
1   1    B  2  foo  10
2   2    A  3  bar  20
3   2    B  4  bar  20
4   3    A  5  baz  30
5   3    B  6  baz  30
```

I would like to reshape the data from a "long" to "wide" format:

```
   ID  XA  XB    Y   Z
0   1   1   2  foo  10
1   2   3   4  bar  20
2   3   5   6  baz  30
```

However, if I use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot()`:

```
df_new = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='TYPE')
```

I will get duplicates of `Y` and `Z`:

```
      X       Y        Z    
TYPE  A  B    A    B   A   B
ID                          
1     1  2  foo  foo  10  10
2     3  4  bar  bar  20  20
3     5  6  baz  baz  30  30
```

To get the desired output, I could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'TYPE': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                   'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Y': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],
                   'Z': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]})


def long_to_wide(df, i, j, varlist):
    df_wide = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='TYPE')
    df_wide.columns = [''.join(col).strip() for col in df_wide.columns.values]
    df_wide.reset_index(inplace=True)

    for var in varlist:
        if pd.Series.equals(df_wide[var + 'A'], df_wide[var + 'B']):
            df_wide.drop((var + 'B'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
        else:
            raise
            # Error handling of some sort...
        df_wide = df_wide.rename(columns={var + 'A': var})

    return df_wide


df_new = long_to_wide(df, 'ID', 'TYPE', ['Y', 'Z'])
```

However, I feel that this must be unnecessarily complicated. For example, to get the desired output in Stata, one could run either:

```
reshape wide X, i(ID) j(TYPE)
```

or

```
reshape wide X, i(ID Y Z) j(TYPE)
```

This situation is quite common and I therefore thought there should be a built-in method to handle it. But after looking around at the `Pandas` documentation and also here at Stack Overflow, I haven't found a simpler solution.

Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a better look at this and the function `pandas.DataFrame.pivot()` is actually performing as expected. Unlike Stata's `reshape`, which is a *command* and does quite a few things under the hood, `pivot()` simply re-arranges the data.

@Heleemur's solution is clever and works great, but usually it will be your responsibility to do the renaming or getting rid of the duplicates.

Here's an intuitive solution based on `pivot()` (or `pivot_table()`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'TYPE': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                   'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Y': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz'],
                   'Z': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]})

wanted = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='TYPE')[[('X','A'), ('X','B'), ('Y','A'), ('Z','A')]].reset_index()
wanted.columns = wanted.columns.get_level_values(0)
wanted.columns = ['ID', 'XA', 'XB', 'Y', 'Z']
wanted

   ID  XA  XB    Y   Z
0   1   1   2  foo  10
1   2   3   4  bar  20
2   3   5   6  baz  30
```

Another way is also the following:

```
wanted = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='TYPE').reset_index()
wanted.columns = [' '.join(col)for col in wanted.columns.values]
wanted = wanted.iloc[:, [0,2] + list(range(1, len(wanted.columns)-1, 2))]
wanted

   ID   X B  X A  Y A  Z A
0    1    2    1  foo   10
1    2    4    3  bar   20
2    3    6    5  baz   30

wanted.columns = ['ID', 'XB', 'XA', 'Y', 'Z']
wanted

   ID  XB  XA    Y   Z
0   1   2   1  foo  10
1   2   4   3  bar  20
2   3   6   5  baz  30
```

In a larger dataframe with more columns, you may want to keep the original names though.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's an equivalent solution to the one from @Heleemur with `pivot_table()`:

```
wanted = df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Y', 'Z'], columns='TYPE').reset_index()
wanted.columns = [''.join(c) for c in wanted.columns.values]
wanted

   ID    Y   Z  XA  XB
0   1  foo  10   1   2
1   2  bar  20   3   4
2   3  baz  30   5   6
```

Comment: Does the pivot_table() solution work if the X column is a string variable? It does not work when I try it.

Comment: Have a look [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442214/pivoting-a-pandas-dataframe-containing-strings-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate).

Answer (score 2):

I did this by setting indexes, merging multiindex column names and resetting indexes. I'm sure this is possible through pivot tables as well (with `df` defined as your sample data frame).

```
df2 = df.set_index(['ID', 'Y', 'Z', 'TYPE']).unstack()
df2.columns = [''.join(c) for c in df2.columns.values]
df2.reset_index()

outputs:

   ID    Y   Z  XA  XB
0   1  foo  10   1   2
1   2  bar  20   3   4
2   3  baz  30   5   6
```