# How to do pivot table with non-numeric data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows

```
name    window_num  channel
----------------------------
Alice   1           cnn
Bob     2           fox
Alice   3           msnbc
```

I would like the data to be in the following format.

```
name    1       2       3 
------------------------------
Alice   cnn     nan     msnbc           
Bob     nan     fox     nan
```

I have tried pandas `pivot_table` method.

`df.pivot_table(index=['name'],columns=['window_num'],values=['channel'])`

But this expects the values column to be numeric for aggregation.

Comment: [Pivoting a Pandas Dataframe containing strings - 'No numeric types to aggregate' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442214/pivoting-a-pandas-dataframe-containing-strings-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all values are necessary and possible duplicated `name, window_num` use `join` function:

```
print (df)
    name  window_num channel
0  Alice           1     cnn <- duplicates name, window_num
1  Alice           1   msnbc <- duplicates name, window_num
2    Bob           2     fox
3  Alice           3   msnbc


df1 = df.pivot_table(index='name',columns='window_num',values='channel', aggfunc=','.join)
print (df1)
window_num          1    2      3
name                             
Alice       cnn,msnbc  NaN  msnbc <- joined data
Bob               NaN  fox    NaN
```

If need only first/last value, so if duplicates next values are removed:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='name',columns='window_num',values='channel', aggfunc='first')
print (df2)
window_num    1    2      3
name                       
Alice       cnn  NaN  msnbc <- first value, duplicated is lost
Bob         NaN  fox    NaN


df3 = df.pivot_table(index='name',columns='window_num',values='channel', aggfunc='last')
print (df3)
window_num      1    2      3
name                         
Alice       msnbc  NaN  msnbc <- las tvalue, duplacated is lost
Bob           NaN  fox    NaN
```

If sure there are not duplicates use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot(index='name',columns='window_num',values='channel')
```

If not sure if duplicates `pivot` failed if dupes in `name, window_num`:

```
print (df)
    name  window_num channel
0  Alice           1     cnn
1  Alice           1   msnbc
2    Bob           2     fox
3  Alice           3   msnbc

df4 = df.pivot(index='name',columns='window_num',values='channel')
print (df4)

>ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```