# Reshaping Pandas DF with non-numeric value only from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to reshape a relatively simple DF (with non-numeric values only)from long to wide, but can't seem get the code working!

I have a table (df1) in the blow format:

| var_1 | var_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Jan |
| B1 | Jan |
| C3 | Jan |
| A2 | Feb |
| B2 | Feb |
| C3 | Mar |

I'm trying to output (df2) into below format:

| Jan | Feb | Mart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | C3 |
| B1 | B2 |  |
| C3 |  |  |

I checked Google and few other links, including below thread :-)

[Pivoting a Pandas Dataframe containing strings - 'No numeric types to aggregate' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442214/pivoting-a-pandas-dataframe-containing-strings-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate)

and closest I came to the solution was with the code

```
df2 = df1.pivot_table(values='va_1', columns='var_2', aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

but, I get an output not quite what I wanted (below):

| Jan | Feb | Mart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1, B1, C3 | A2, B2 | C3 |

Appreciate all help that could get me from df1 to df2!

Thanks! :-)

Nad

Comment: leave out the `aggfunc` parameter, which combines lists into comma-separated strings

Comment: Thanks for the comment - but, without the aggfunc, I get the below error:

    raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index for each group using [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) then pivot with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var_1': ['A1', 'B1', 'C3', 'A2', 'B2', 'C3'],
    'var_2': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar']
})

# New row numbers based on relative group row numbers
df['g'] = df.groupby('var_2').cumcount()
df = (
    df.pivot(index='g', columns='var_2')
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)  # Clean Up levels
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)  # Cleanup Axis Names
        .rename_axis(None)
)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   Feb Jan  Mar
0   A2  A1   C3
1   B2  B1  NaN
2  NaN  C3  NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks! This snippet gets me to the output I'm after :-) 
Nad